# Avada custom css settings not taking effect

Tags: wordpress

I'm having all sorts of errors with header images not changing and custom css (made in avada or child theme) not taking any effect. I'm on a fresh install of Avada (5.6.2) on Wordpress (Version 4.9.8) and all sorts of stuff is already going wrong in making small changes. I'm hosted on wpengine.

How to fix this? Is this a caching issue or server or something else?

Comment: did you purged cache?

Comment: yeah...tried that many times.

Comment: Is your child theme itself working? Have you follow the codex documentation for setting up the stylesheets in functions.php for your chlid and parent theme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have both of the following set up correctly?

Style.css in child:

```
/*
 Theme Name:   Twenty Fifteen Child
 Theme URI:    http://example.com/twenty-fifteen-child/
 Description:  Twenty Fifteen Child Theme
 Author:       John Doe
 Author URI:   http://example.com
 Template:     twentyfifteen
 Version:      1.0.0
 License:      GNU General Public License v2 or later
 License URI:  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 Tags:         light, dark, two-columns, right-sidebar, responsive-layout, accessibility-ready
 Text Domain:  twenty-fifteen-child
*/
```

Functions.php in child:

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

}
?>
```

Taken from: https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Have you then enqueued the style sheet you want to use?

```
<?php
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'parent-style'; // This is 'twentyfifteen-style' for the Twenty Fifteen theme.

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
?>
```

Comment: it was a caching issue. Turned off chrome cache.

Comment: Nice, I open up inspector tools and will right click on refresh which gives you the options to clear the cache, do a hard refresh etc. etc which helps to avoid that occuring

Answer (score 1):

First things You probably did and didn't help a bit.

1. avada / options / performance / scroll down to "reset avada caches"
2. if have autooptimise installed, look to top wp admin menu, hover "autooptimise" and click clear css/js cache

Now the fun stuff.

1. If You are editing - Avada / options / custom css, make sure that in top wp menu you have picked "show all languages", if You by some chance picked like "Deutsch" in there and do changes to Avada custom css, those changes will never show on English version of page, English page will have old css, so make sure You are in "all languages" which will update all languages. This can also affect some plugins and so on.
2. Even more fun stuff is when Your custom CSS show on page only when You are logged in. When You log off You will see old css. This is caused because avada store this Css into page source and not in separate css, and web hostings tend to cache these things in cloudflare or nginx cache or this stuff. You can check this easily by going to your [www.page.com](http://www.page.com) in chrome, right click to show source and look at custom css, then go to [www.page.com?v=1](http://www.page.com?v=1) (just added random parameter to change link) , rightclick check page source, if You see new css here but old at original page, hosting caching is causing You issues.
   **Solution 1** - wait a day, it will eventually change (boring right)
   **Solution 2** - Go to edit page for homepage and update/save it even with no actual changes (or add blank space somewhere :D) , this will force page source refresh.